# Lenovo Scrollpoint mouse sensitivity still wrong

Tags: drivers, xorg, mouse, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Scrollpoint mouse which is really nice, but in Windows you need to install a mouse driver suite to get the sensitivity of the scrollpoint right.  I've just plugged it into my Ubuntu laptop and it's way too sensitive.

I've been doing some research and this site: https://github.com/pdewacht/hid-scrollpoint/

says:

*Peter Ganzhorn contributed a patch to libinput 1.11 to fix Scrollpoint sensitivity. From that release on, scroll sensitivity should be fine out of the box. (libinput is used by current Xorg and by Wayland.)*

But it doesn't seem to be in the version of Ubuntu (22.04/Jammy) I'm using.
I've tried some of the fixes to libinput rules and compiling the module with dkms and nothing's changed.

```
$ xinput list-props 14
    Device 'HID 04b3:3108':
    Device Enabled (177):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (179): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (323):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (324):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (342): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (343): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (344):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (345):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (346):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (347):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (330): -0.600000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (331): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (332):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (333):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (334):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (335): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (336): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (300): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (301):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (302):    0, 0
    Device Node (303):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (304):    1203, 12552
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (337):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (338):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (339):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (340):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (341):    1
```

I've tried changing these variables and it doesn't improve anything.  As you can see, I now have a module 'hid_lenovo' operational.  Think one problem mentioned elsewhere was the order the drivers are loaded could be a source of confusion, but I've tried removing them one by one and still the scrollpoint is way too fast. So I'm stuck with this now.

```
$ lsmod | grep "hid"
hid_scrollpoint        16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
hid_lenovo             28672  0
mac_hid                16384  0
hid_apple              16384  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   151552  5 hid_scrollpoint,usbhid,hid_apple,hid_generic,hid_lenovo
```